# Dynamic MySQL query: Join results from numerous tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

Something I've been stumbling on for a while now. I have a table called `gears` which contains rows with the names: `id`, `mid`, `cid` and `installed`. I want to search this table and return in csv format a list of `mid`s for some unique `cid`. For example if `cid = $cid` I can use:

```
$query = $database -> query("SELECT COUNT(mid), GROUP_CONCAT(mid) FROM gears WHERE cid=$cid", __LINE__, __FILE__);
$gears_installed = $database -> get_result($query);
$gears = $database -> get_result($query, 0, 1);
```

Don't worry about the function names, they do exactly as one would expect. So if there were 3 rows for that specific `$cid`, with `mid`s: `bank`, `lottery` and `post` then `$gears_installed` would be equal to 3 and `$gears` would be equal to `bank,lottery,post`. This works as intended.

Now on to the question I have. Each unique `mid` has its own table, named `settings_mid_here`. I.e, for the above three, I have the tables `settings_bank`, `settings_lottery` and finally `settings_post`. Each of these tables will also have a column called `cid` (this is how the two can be related). How do I go about running one query to return the entire row from each table where `cid=$cid`? I do not want to run a separate query for `SELECT * FROM settings_bank WHERE cid=$cid` and `SELECT * FROM settings_post WHERE cid=$cid` and finally `SELECT * FROM settings_post WHERE cid=$cid`, as this could result in around 10 extra queries on one page load (there are, at the moment, 10 different `mid`s).

As you can see, the problem is dynamic. It must be able to adapt to a different number of `mid`s, somehow differentiate the settings within each table (for example `settings_bank` may have a column with name `name`, and so might `settings_post`). Finally, it must also be able to return a default row (not null values) if there does not exist a row corresponding to the given `$cid`.

A complicated task but I hope someone can help me with this as I have not been able to get anywhere.

Comment: I have some ideas, but I could only help if I'd have a dump of some of the scheme and some demo data to test the queries. Otherwise it would simply by a smart guess.

Comment: You mean that you would create a new table every time a new `mid` appeared in the `gears` table?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc5ce/1

Use cid=3

Comment: @geomagas The `gears` table can include a specific `mid` multiple times. The `gears` table will have one row for each `mid` installed on one `cid` account, so to speak. Each `mid` is a widget, for example.

Comment: Yes, but that's not what I asked. Suppose I add a line in `gears` that contains a `mid='somewidget'` that wasn't there before. Do I have to create a `settings_somewidget` table too?

Comment: If I were to create a widget called `somewidget`, then I would also create the `settings_somewidget` table at the same time. I'm basically working on a widget-plugin sort of system.

Comment: Why not just have a 'global' `settings` table with an extra `mid` field? Wouldn't _that_ make your 'dynamic' problems dissapear?

Comment: At the moment I have a table called `core`. This has the generic columns (of which `cid` is included) and then columns such as: `currency_name`, `currency_sign`, `currency_interest` etc etc and `post_name`, `post_amount `etc etc. The problem is, there are about 50 columns in total and this will only increase. Not only that, but there are so many redundant columns if the value is not found in the  `gear` table.

Answer (score 2):

```
$queries = array();
foreach(explode(',', $gears) as $gear) {
    $queries[] = "SELECT '$gear' AS gearname, settings_$gear.* FROM settings_$gear WHERE cid=$cid";
}
$sql = implode(' UNION ', $queries);
$query2 = $database->query($sql);
```

This query will return one row for each table, with an extra `gearname` column to indicate which table that row came from.

Or you can create a JOIN dynamically:

```
$gears_array = explode(',', $gears);
$joins = implode(' JOIN ', $gears_array);
$wheres = implode(' AND ',
                  array_map(function($g) use ($cid) {
                    return "$g.cid = $cid";
                  }, $gears_array));
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $joins WHERE $wheres";
$query2 = $database->query($sql);
```

Comment: I have run this for a test case:

`SELECT 'currency' AS gearname, * FROM settings_currency WHERE cid=3`

but this gives an error (due to the `'currency' AS gearname` part).

Comment: Fixed it. MySQL requires an explicit tablename before `*` when doing this.

Comment: This works great until the two tables have a different number of columns (which is the case for me) - at which point it falls apart and throws an error.

Comment: I have thought of doing something similar to `SELECT a.*, b.* FROM settings_currency a LEFT JOIN settings_post b ON b.cid=a.cid WHERE a.cid=$cid`, except I do not know how to make this work for multiple tables and this now has the problem of not being able to differentiate columns from its original table. For example, there will be two columns named `name`, one from `settings_currency` and one from `settings_post`.

Comment: I've added a JOIN solution. Although I wonder how the application will deal with all this dynamic data -- if the tables have different schemas, how will the application know what's in the result?

Comment: You'll have to distinguish them by position in the result, not by name.

Comment: The application creates an associate array with the settings for each widget. There are different class files for each widget which then accesses the array as it needs to (by their key).

Comment: if the application knows all the column names, you can make it generate subqueries for each table, e.g. `FROM (SELECT col1 as currency_col1, col2 as currency_col2, ... FROM settings_currency WHERE cid=$cid) as settings_currency`

Comment: And the `JOIN` solution works nicely but unfortunately to make this dynamic I would need it to either return each result in a new row (like in the `UNION` solution) or prepend each column name with the `mid`. Is either possible (preferably the former)?

EDIT: Unfortunately, I am trying to make this as dynamic as possible, even allowing for users to create their own widgets. As such it's not an easy task to keep track of the column names and use it in the queries.

Comment: Prepending the column names is what I suggested in my last comment.

Comment: If you need to get more dynamic than this, I think you'll need to look up the column names in `information_schema`.

Comment: Is it possible to prepend all column names when using `*`?

Comment: No, it's not possible. I would have suggested that long ago if it were.

Comment: Hmm, okay. Thanks for your help. I will take a look into using `information_schema` to get the column names and prepending, but if that doesn't work I will have to rename the column names so that they are unique (which is annoying from a syntactic point of view, but will be done if it is necessary!).

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer to your specific question, simply because *there's no way to accomplish what you are trying with one query*.

The reason is simple: RDBMSs are not designed to work this way. Tables are supposed to store *data* that represent *entities* and *relations*. In your case, for each distinct value of `mid`, a table named `settings_{mid}` must exist, thus forcing the `mid` column implicitly store (a part of) a *table name*. But that's not data, that's *metadata*.

That would not really be a problem if SQL syntax could accept variable, parametrized, column-related or arbitary table names. But it doesn't. And that's *by design*. Instead, an RDBMS provides you with all the tools you could ever need to relate your data to each other. By using it the intended way, you'll never have to resort to such 'dynamic' tricks.

In your case, there should be *one* `config` table with a `mid` column to distinguish the rows that refer to the specific `mid` value. Then, the query would be simple:

```
select * from `config` where mid='$mid' and cid='$cid'
```

This is the relational way. Thus the *R* in *RDBMS*. There's absolutely no reason at all to mix data with metadata. If you do, you move the relation resolution problem in higher levels of the application model.

And one last thing: One might argue that the `config_{mid}` tables might have similar but not identical structure. There's a solution for that too: [IS-A relations](http://www.geomagas.gr/index.php/is-a-relations-in-relational-databases/).

Having said that, for your specific problem, a solution along the lines of Barmar's answer would do the trick.

Comment: I initially thought along the lines of using a `config` table, but as there are an arbitrary number of 'settings' for each `mid` this isn't really possible.

Comment: Apart from the IS-A approach I mentioned, if the structure cannot be classified in any useful way, you could still implement this using a key/value pair table: `CONFIG(mid,cid,setting_name,setting_value)`. But avoid an arbitary number of tables; you're only making it worse.

Comment: Actually, I really like this idea, thanks. Would you recommend creating two tables, i.e `setting_ids` which have 3 columns: `sid`, `mid`, `setting_name` (so each setting can be defined here) and another table which houses each instance of a setting for each `cid`, having columns: `id`, `sid`, `cid`, `setting_val`. So in the first table I could have a row: `sid=1`, `mid=bank`, `setting_name=sign` and then in the other table have the rows with vals: `cid=345`, `setting_val=£`; `cid=24`, `setting_val=$` -> both rows have `sid=1`.

Comment: In fact, I'd recommend a somewhat more complex schema, with the necessary (even the not-that-necessary) constraints and structure. But that's not a subject to be discussed in comments. I recommend opening a fresh topic addressing these concerns, so that others may contribute as well. I'd be happy to participate.